# Chrome Extension Manifest Returns Error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

No matter what I do, the manifest returns the following error:

```
 Could not load extension from 
 '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lab/chrome/test'. Manifest is not valid JSON.
 Line: 28, column: 2, Trailing comma not allowed.
```

But I have referred and copied it from the dev site hosted by chrome. I am stuck in the very first step. Below is my manifest

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Same Extention",
  "version": "1",

  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "A description",



 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],

}
```

Chrome Documentations I referred: [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) & [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma at the end of your `content_scripts` array.

Instead of:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Try:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```