# Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 18, column: 2, Trailing comma not allowed

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "icons": {"16":  "images/icon16.png",
            "24":  "images/icon24.png",
            "32":  "images/icon32.png",
            "128":  "images/icon128.png"},
  "permissions": [
    "https://*.wikipedia.com"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "test",
      "default_icon": "images/icon128.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
}
```

Hello !
This is the manifest.json file from my test extension.
Whenever I try to import it in Chrome it says: "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 18, column: 2, Trailing comma not allowed"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension Manifest Returns Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683779/chrome-extension-manifest-returns-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a problem in line `"manifest_version": 2,` usage of an unnecessary comma.

Comment: @Laurent9999 Welcome to Stackoverflow. When someone give you a good and fast answer, you could vote for his answer and tag the question as answered. So, other contributors don't loose time by reading answered question.

Comment: I got it you need to add '/' at the end of the URL. It's a problem with the release of manifest version 2.